# Не получается сформировать Expression по string, состоящего из нескольких свойств

Tags: c#, expressions

Есть `Expression`:

```
Expression<Func<Test, bool>> expressionWhereTest = (t => true);//по умолчанию все
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test),"t");
Expression conditions = null;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Value))
            {
                var left1 = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(Test.T1));
                var left2 = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(Test.T2));
                var right = Expression.Constant(filter.Value, typeof(string));

                var left = Expression.Add(left1,left2, typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }));
                var condition = Expression.Equal(left, right);

                conditions = conditions == null ? condition : Expression.AndAlso(conditions, condition);
            }
        }

expressionWhereTest = conditions == null ? expressionWhereTest : Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, bool>>(conditions, parameter);
Console.WriteLine(expressionWhereTest);
```

Получаю такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно так:

`list.Where(t => $"{t.T1}.{t.T2}" == "1a.2a")`

Как мне вставить точку?

Comment: что то вы не то делаете. Где ваш [`string.format`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ2vM.png)?

Comment: @tym32167 немного не понимаю как использовать мне его в `Expression`? Я так понеимаю что вместо `Add` у меня должно быть что то другое?

Comment: По идее да, вызов функции string.format

Comment: @tym32167 но я ж не могу ее так вызвать...у меня параметры типа `Expression`, а `format` хочет `string`

Comment: @tym32167 т.е. как я понимаю мне нужно что то на подобии `Expression.Call()`... только которое примет не 1 `Expression`, а несколько

Comment: Как вызвать функцию через выражения я не помню :)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо и на этом :) буду копать )

Comment: С помощью `Concat` вы объединили _две_ строки: `T1` и `T2`. А нужно объединять _три_: `T1`, `.`, `T2`. По-моему, так.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov [так все работает](http://prntscr.com/pt74za)...но хотелось бы именно через вызов `string.format`

Comment: @tym32167 еще раз спасибо, вы натолкнули меня на верную мысль

Comment: На здоровье! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Expression<Func<Test, bool>> expressionWhereTest = (t => true);//по умолчанию все
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test),"t");
Expression conditions = null;

var right = Expression.Constant(filter.Value, typeof(string));

var parameters = new Expression[]
{
    Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(Test.T1)),
    Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(Test.T2))
};

var method = new Func<string, object[], string>(string.Format).Method;
Expression callStringFormat = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Constant("{0}.{1}"), Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), parameters));
var condition = Expression.Equal(callStringFormat, right);
conditions = conditions == null ? condition : Expression.AndAlso(conditions, condition);

expressionWhereTest = conditions == null ? expressionWhereTest : Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, bool>>(conditions, parameter);

Console.WriteLine(expressionWhereTest);
```